# How to parse JSON from Azure App Configuration into an strongly typed object

Tags: json, azure, configuration, azure-functions, azure-app-configuration

I'm trying to parse JSON from Azure App Configuration into my Azure function but I get `null`.
Am I doing something wrong?

The **Key** is "Site" and **Value** is

```
{
  "SiteUrl": "url",
  "TitleXpath": "xpath"
}
```

Here is the class I'm trying to parse JSON into:

```
public class SiteData
{
    public string SiteUrl { get; set; }

    public string TitleXpath { get; set; }
}
```

In my Azure Function, I get `null` as a result when I'm trying to parse it into a `SiteData` obj.

```
var site = _configuration.GetValue<SiteData>("Site");
```

However this works:

```
var site = _configuration.GetValue<string>("Site");
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this problem by:

- Using as Content-Type `application/json`
- Using `_configuration.GetSection("Site").Get<SiteData>()`